# Rear strut mounts 2005 Escape

Tags: ford, noise, suspension, struts

I have a 2005 Ford Escape. Going over bumps, I get a loud banging noise from the rear struts. There’s play when I grab the upper part of the shock. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: It could be the mount but it has no rubber, just a steel part, it could be the rubbers that come with the shock to mount it in the upper mount have split and fallen out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a 2005 Escape XLT (FWD) that may have had a similar issue, based on your brief description of your issue.  What ended up happening was the whole upper shock mount on the passenger rear ended up rusting out, causing the shock to not have any support on the top, and causing a very unsafe condition.  It didn't pop into the passenger compartment, but made an awful banging and metal flexing noise over any uneven surface.  There really wasn't any reasonable way to repair (at least not any repair that was within the justifiable budget range of a 12 year old vehicle), so we traded it in for a newer used vehicle.

In your case, I'd suggest taking it to a qualified mechanic for them to diagnose, as it could either be a rusted out shock mount, a broken shock, and there isn't enough information in your post to know what's going on, especially without pictures.

Comment: This seems to describe my exact condition. Just happens to be the right rear on mine as well. The noise sounds exactly the same and I can wiggle the shock near the no longer existing mount. Thanks!

Comment: @AlexVolpe, I don't know if ours was caused by normal corrosion (we live in Iowa with lots of winter road salt and other ice-melting chemicals), or latent damage from an accident on that side of the vehicle about 10 years ago that didn't actually hit the rear quarter panel, but did significant damage at the B pillar (got T-boned right at the B pillar and crunched in both right doors, but didn't dent the front or rear quarters).  The left side seemed fine with no corrosion evident.  But in any case, we decided it was not worth repairing.